# UIKIT Grid columns not staying adjacent to each other

Tags: html, getuikit

I am using uikit 2.8.0. I am trying to create a two column grid structure. But the two columns don't appear adjacent to each other. The second column slides down the first one.

```
<body>
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-large-bottom">
<nav var code.......>
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
<div class="uk-width-medium-1-1 uk-text-center">
<h1>Tell us more about yourself</h1>
</div>
</div>

<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-match="{target:'.equal-height'}">
<div class="uk-width-large-6-10" style="margin: 0 20% 0 20%;">
<div class="uk-width-7-10 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-width-medium-7-10 uk-width-large-7-10"    style="border: 1px solid #B4B3B3;height:100px;">
</div>
<div class="uk-width-3-10 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-width-medium-3-10 uk-width-large-3-10" style="border: 1px solid #B4B3B3;height:100px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried many options. But come what may, the second grid would not stay side by side to the first one.

How can I fix this? Any tool that I can use to debug the layout? I am using chrome developer tools without any success.

Comment: In Version 2.20 same issue comes up with my project as well.  Any idea here?

Answer (score 2):

You needed to add class ".uk-grid" to the div with styled margin (uk-width-large-6-10), as you want to make a grid inside that element.

Plus this, the "Target" element should target to something existing, best to "uk-panel" placed inside the element with "uk-width".

```
<div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-large-bottom">
<nav var code.......>
<div class="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin>
    <div class="uk-width-medium-1-1 uk-text-center">
        <h1>Tell us more about yourself</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-large-6-10 uk-grid" style="margin: 0 20% 0 20%;"  data-uk-grid-match="{target:'.uk-panel'}">
        <div class="uk-width-7-10 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-width-medium-7-10 uk-width-large-7-10"    style="background-color:green; height:100px;">
            <div class="uk-panel"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-width-3-10 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-width-medium-3-10 uk-width-large-3-10" style="background-color:red; height:100px;">
            <div class="uk-panel"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```